# Android ADT Bundle doesn't recognize layout xml file from a android-maven project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, maven-2, adt

I am trying to import my Android-Maven project to ADT bundle Eclipse. I have installed the m2e plug-in for eclipse.

When I click on a layout file after my import, I could not see the phone screen layout view, instead, there are some word says "The project target is not set. Right click project, choose Properties | Android.".

[image]

I did not see there's any Android option in project Properties as the capture below.

[image]

Is there any special config I need to do in order to let it be recognized?

thank you

Comment: These question needs more information, such as your POM and whether you have the m2e-android connector installed?